# Who is growing faster?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

I am trying to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} { 2^{n^2} \over n!} = \infty$. I can't use l'Hôpital's rule (or I dnon't know how) and I don't recall any other method which could help me. It also isn't obvious to me that exponential is growing faster than factorial. How do I prove that?

Comment: Do you mean that $\lim_{n\to \infty} { 2^{n^2} \over n!} = \infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $2^{x^2}=\exp(\log (2^{x^2}))=\exp(x^2 \log 2)$, then use Stirling to approximate $x!$.